# How to filter MS-Project Tasks in Timeline using VBA

Tags: vba, timeline, ms-project

I'm trying to filter tasks in my Project 2013 file, by select only tasks marked with "Show on Timeline" checkbox.
I use VBA to do this filtering but every Task in my loopreturn with TaskOnTimeline = True
even only 12 tasks (out of 190) marked as such.

This is my code I'm using:

```
Set appProj = CreateObject("Msproject.Application")
appProj.FileOpen GanttPath
Set GNT = appProj.ActiveProject
appProj.Visible = True
For Each iTask In GNT.Tasks 
  If TaskOntimeline Then
    G1 = iTask.name
    G2 = iTask.ID
    G3 = iTask.UniqueID
    G4 = iTask.Start
    G5 = iTask.Finish
  End if
Next
appProj.FileCloseEx
appProj.Quit
```

I will put those values in Array for farther processing and display.

Why all tasks return the same value?
What should I do better so it will filter accurately?

Regards,

Comment: Where is the code where you place your Filter ?

Comment: The filter will come inside the For loop for every Task iTask where TaskOnTimeline is True. For now, any task return with true value.

Comment: when you use `If TaskOnTimeline Then` it adds the Task to the Timeline. Looked everywhere online, couldn't think of a way to "cheat" this, yet...

Comment: OK, So how I can get "Show on Timeline" value of a Task? is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Still looking for creative ways, so far only able to add tasks ore remove tasks from timeline, not to get the value